# DevExpress TabbedView Freeze Focused Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a `TabbedView` with multiple Panels
on each Panel I have a button for edit/save/cancel
i need to `freeze` all other Panels when I am editing one of them

I have an event on `Edit Button` and can read all Panels in `TabbedView` and make

```
dockPanel1.Enabled = false;
```

the problem is when they are on same `panelContainer` like in the image
[image]

i would like to freeze the other `Tabs`
with Enabled = false the `Panel` is disabled but the user can click on `Tab`, and I want to restrict him to view other panels

any suggestion is welcome

Answer (score 0):

You would have to disable each control within each of the tab, this would probably be best handled on the click event of the tab.

Just spin through the tabView.controls object and set each control enabled or disabled based on whether you want them enabled or disabled.

Comment: yes, the control is disabled , but i can still click on tab and see the control

Comment: the user should see only the editable control, and nothing more he can do